# How to calculate a mean value from multiple maximal values

Tags: r, max

I have a variable e.g. `c(0, 8, 7, 15, 85, 12, 46, 12, 10, 15, 15)`

how can I calculate a mean value out of random maximal values in R?

for example, I would like to calculate a mean value with three maximal values?

Comment: I would say your post is not very clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- First step: You draw a sample of 3 from your data and store it in x
- Second step: You calculate the mean of the sample

try

```
dat <- c(0,8,7,15, 85, 12, 46, 12, 10, 15,15)

x <- sample(dat,3)
x
mean(x)
```

possible output:

```
> x <- sample(dat,3)
> x
[1] 85 15  0
> mean(x)
[1] 33.33333
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the three highest values, just sort your vector and subset:

```
> mean(sort(c(0,8,7,15, 85, 12, 46, 12, 10, 15,15), decreasing=T)[1:3])
[1] 48.66667
```